# Adding OpenVPN client connection to cron

Tags: vpn, cron, openvpn

I wrote simple server-client OpenVPN config files:

server.conf

```
dev tun0
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
```

client.conf

```
dev tun0
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.1
remote 192.168.0.123
```

which basically is a cleartext OpenVPN tunnel - for now on its ok to me, I just learn it from basics, the point is - yay, it works! :)

I also wrote a tiny simple bash script to automatically run client:

```
#!/bin/bash
openvpn --config client.conf
```

and saved as `run.sh`. Then, wanted to add it to `cron` to allow client connect to vpn server at the time I want.

I did:

```
crontab -e
11 5 * * * /home/mirx/run.sh
```

but I dont see any connected client on server site - does my cron entry work or not? On client site I dont see any new `tun` interface when I check it with `ifconfig`. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `chmod +x run.sh`?

Comment: @EEAA: yes, I did

Comment: Did you test this script manually to verify that it works as intended?

Comment: @EEAA: yup, when I run `./run.sh` it worked and connected to my server

Comment: please see my updated run.sh

Comment: The path to openvpn won't be in the path for cron - simples but you'll find that out when you work your way through the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Your script must use full path to configuration file, as cron daemon does not run as your user (nor from your home directory).

```
#!/bin/bash
openvpn --config /home/mirx/client.conf
```

**Also make sure you are editing root's cronjob as you need root to connect to openvpn network**

**Update 2**

Also it seems you might have your corn syntax mixed, have this header to help you set it up :

```
#minute (0-59),
#|      hour (0-23),
#|      |       day of the month (1-31),
#|      |       |       month of the year (1-12),
#|      |       |       |       day of the week (0-6 with 0=Sunday).
#|      |       |       |       |       commands
```

**Old Answer**

I recommend placing ampersand (&) at the end to make sure it runs in the background:

```
11 5 * * * /home/mirx/run.sh &
```

This way you can check if it is running or kill it if needed with `ps ax | grep 'run.sh'`

Also, if you are using any variables like $HOME or relative paths in your `run.sh` script it will not work, as cron is ran as a separate user which usually does not have access to most of your environment variables.

Comment: Hmm, did everything you wrote and still dont have any incoming connections in my server

Comment: are you editing crontab of root user? As openvpn requires root privileges to run properly.

Comment: yes, checkes as root - same result = no connection

Comment: can you try setting it to `/home/mirx/run.sh &> /tmp/cron.log` and then check if you get any output in /tmp/cron.log file. If you do not, then either cron daemon is not running or you have your time mixed up.  I have added an example header you can use in your crontab file to help you setup times. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: my cron.log is empty

Comment: but cron is running, checked with `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep`

Comment: but you did not create the file manually? If it was created by cron process then it means the script is being run. Can you also use full path to openvpn binary (you can find where it is by this command: `which openvpn`). Also the problem might be that cron user does not have sufficient privileges to access a tun/tap device.

Comment: Ok, tried it once again. I did everything as root: 1) wrote client config: http://pastie.org/private/r0kyhqrmyeqtgrgcvy00pq 2) wrote client run script: http://pastie.org/private/qvcltjyfcjpaujxdtaeffq 3) did `chmod u+x run.sh` 4) added line to crontab: `1 4 * * * /tmp/run.sh &> /tmp/cron.log` ... and still nothing. Cron is working (checked again with `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep`) and file `cron.log` is empty (I didnt create it it was created by cron) - finally, connected to server, many, many thanks :D but why `cron.log` is empty btw?